# How to make a buffer-local key binding in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

I've been working on an Emacs minor mode lately and part of its functionality was displaying images in separate buffers. So far I've been using a function like this:

```
(defun create-buffer-with-image (name)
  (let ((buffer (generate-new-buffer name))
        (image (get-svg-for-kanji-code name)))
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)
    (turn-on-iimage-mode)
    (iimage-mode-buffer t)
    (insert-image image)))
```

and it produces a buffer with the image passed as argument, but closing the buffer requires hitting <kbd>C-x k</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd>, which started to get cumbersome after a while. The way to simplify closing of such transient buffers would be to have a key binding for the `kill-this-buffer` function, but it would need to be buffer-specific, so as not to mess up anything else. The question is how to make such a binding with the creation of a buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a bit mislead by some posts on the web suggesting the use of `local-key-binding`, but somehow it did not work for me - when the image was displayed and I examined the key bindings, my choice of `q` was not in effect. After some experimentation and digging through `elisp` references I found that I needed to use `local-set-key`. So now my function looks like this:

```
(defun create-buffer-with-image (name)
  (let ((buffer (generate-new-buffer name))
        (image (get-svg-for-kanji-code name)))
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)
    (local-set-key (kbd "q") 'kill-this-buffer)
    (turn-on-iimage-mode)
    (iimage-mode-buffer t)
    (insert-image image)))
```

and the newly created image buffer can easily be closed by pressing <kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: `local-set-key` modifies the local key map, which in most cases is the major mode keymap, which will affect *all* buffers using that major mode. So `local-set-key` is **not** a buffer-local effect. (It's only "local" as opposed to the "global" key map which is visible to every buffer.)

Comment: Thanks for your response, @phils. I did some investigation regarding your remark. When I display the image using `iimage-mode`, the major mode for that buffer is `Fundamental` (additional minor modes are `iImg` and `MRev`). I examined the keybindings in all these modes after making the `local-set-key` binding and none of them showed the behavior you warned me about. The way I see it in light of this is that it really causes a buffer-local effect. Correct me if I'm missing something important here.

Comment: In `fundamental-mode` that is correct. It doesn't set a local keymap, and it appears that `local-set-key` in this circumstance does create a buffer-local keymap. Just be aware that this is not the normal behaviour, as most major modes do set (and share) a local keymap.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep an eye on it :)

Comment: Your solution with local-set-key and the peculiarities of fundamental-mode is very useful. You should accept it as the solution to your original question so that it will be singled out when we visit this page.

Answer (score 10):

From EmacsWiki:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferLocalKeys

For buffer-local keys, you cannot use `local-set-key`, unless you want to modify the keymap of the entire major-mode in question: `local-set-key` is local to a major-mode, not to a buffer.

For buffer-local modifications, use this instead:

```lisp
(use-local-map (copy-keymap foo-mode-map))
(local-set-key "d" 'some-function)
```

Written by:   TiagoSaboga

---

To inspect the change, type `C-h b` aka `M-x describe-bindings`

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you add a call to `special-mode` after the call to `switch-to-buffer`.
In the longer run, you'll want to use your own major mode, so you'd do:

```
(define-derived-mode my-image-mode special-mode "MyImage"
  "My own major mode to display images."
  ;; We could add more things here
  )

(defun create-buffer-with-image (name)
  (with-current-buffer (generate-new-buffer name)
    (my-image-mode)
    (let ((image (get-svg-for-kanji-code name)))
      (turn-on-iimage-mode)
      (iimage-mode-buffer t)
      (insert-image image)
      (pop-to-bffer (current-buffer)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a minor mode:

```
(define-minor-mode my-mode "my doc" nil nil (make-sparse-keymap))
```

Then you can use this mode's `my-mode-map` to define your keybindings. Activate the mode with `(my-mode)`.